# How can prokaryotes repair double strand breaks by homologous recombination if they're haploids?

Tags: recombination, dna-damage, prokaryotes

Title says it all, I must be going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Several answers to this question:

1. Much of the time what bacteria are doing to repair DSBs is actually [non-homologous end-joining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-homologous_end_joining), which does not require strict homology. This is the more likely mechanism earlier in the cell cycle when copy number is more likely to be ~1.
2. If cells have completed DNA replication (later in the cell cycle), there are at minimum 2 copies of all DNAs present in the cell. [These can be used for homologous recombination.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_directed_repair)
3. Bacterial chromosome copy number can be [overreplicated in some situations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1479556/), such that DNA replication is not synchronized to the cell cycle and is more than normal for a cell. In these situations copy number can be >2.